# How to make two columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border, multiple-columns

[CLICK HERE TO SEE WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE RIGHT NOW!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0bFs.png)

[CLICK HERE TO SEE MY GOAL-ish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVv9h.png)

*(had to hide my name and face for privacy names in the picture and censor my name in the html)*

**1.** So basically I was wondering how I could put the text and the image in two separate columns side by side?

**2.** Also, I don't know how to remove that space between the header and main part. I'm sorry if this seems ridiculous.

**HTML** (*not all of it, just the important part*):

```
<h4>My Portfolio</h4>
    
<nav>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Education.html">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
      
</nav>
```

```
<div class="intro">
  
  <p>
    <b>Hi!</b>
    <br>
    My name is <b>insert my name here</b> and I am a first year <b>computer science</b> student.
  </p>

    <img src="Me.jpg" alt="A picture of me in front of pink flowers" width="500" height="500">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{margin-left: 10%; 
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

header{
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h4{
    padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: #a989d6;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
}

.intro{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

main{
    background-color: #dfcff6;
}

footer{
    background-color: #a989d6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using frameworks like bootstrap?

Comment: Can you please add the rest of your HTML to reproduce what your first image shows?

Comment: I mean, we haven't learned that yet so I don't really know how to make that work

Comment: added the other part of the html

Comment: @arinaaa Create 2 divs inside your intro div and set their width to 50% in CSS. Once you are able to do it this way, take a look at the Grid Layout in HTML/CSS to improve your current design: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: @EKrol two divs? like one for the paragraph and one for the image?

Comment: @arinaaa If that's your goal then yes. Whatever you put in those divs will appear in them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use display grid for the columns. But it should work with display flex also.

For the space remove the margin and padding.

Something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <style>

        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container{
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: yellow;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }

        .content{
            display: grid;
            place-items: center;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using flex:

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dfcff6;
}
body{
margin-left: 10%; 
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">

  <p>
    <b>Hi!</b>
    <br> My name is <b>insert my name here</b> and I am a first year <b>computer science</b> student.
  </p>

  <img src="https://fotojoker.pl/blog/wp-content/uploads/autor-300x300.jpg" alt="Another photo because I have not original :)" width="500" height="500">

</div>
```